# Significado de "__"

Tags: c, linux, terminologia

Na [implementação do kernel do Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff2d8b19a3a62559afba1c53360c8577a7697714/include/linux/kernel.h), me deparei essa declaração na linha 89:

```
#define _THIS_IP_ ({ __label__ __here; __here: (unsigned long)&&__here; })
```

Eu sei que em `C`, símbolos começando com um `_` seguido por uma letra maiúscula ou outro `_` são reservados para a implementação, o que significa isso na prática?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isto significa que se você declarar um símbolo (variável, função, macro, etc.) desta forma, você pode entrar em conflito com símbolos exportados pela implementação do compilador ou da biblioteca padrão.

Por exemplo, você pode tentar criar uma uma função:

```
void minha_funcao(int _Param);
```

Mas a sua implementação declara em algum lugar a macro:

```
#define _Param 1
```

Desta forma vai ocorrer um erro de sintaxe, pois o preprocessador vai substituir a macro pelo valor 1.

Answer (score 15):

A utilização de dois sublinhados ('__') em identificadores está reservado para uso interno do compilador de acordo com a **Norma Técnica ANSI-C**. Na prática, isso é feito para evitar uma colisão com nomes definidos pelo desenvolvedor.

> Em C, símbolos começando com um sublinhado seguido por uma letra
>   maiúscula ou outro sublinhado são reservados para a implementação.
>   Você como um usuário de C não deve criar quaisquer símbolos que
>   começam com as sequências reservados

Detalhes

- [Programming languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)
- [Programando em Linguagem ANSI C](ftp://ftp.dca.fee.unicamp.br/pub/docs/vonzuben/ea869_1s04/linguagemC2.pdf)